# How to run function on specific days of every week?

Tags: php, date, calendar

Basically I am trying to run a function on very specific days of every week. It would be hard for me to put in the words so I will put an image crossing out the days I want to run. Though I will try my best what I want achieve and what have I done so far. So far this has been my approach firstly I am getting current date, week number of the month and working days starting from (1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday). So I am able to get it right for only January but not the following months as it resets for each month. for example, On Jan 31st I am running the function then in the next month it shouldn't run on Monday in 1st week of February instead it should be running on Tuesday and Thursday as it already ran the function on Friday 31st Jan following the pattern of previous month. May I know If I am on the right track? It would be helpful for me to learn this concept if anyone has suggestions or advice. (send email is the function I want to run).

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$week = ceil( date( 'j', strtotime( $date ) ) / 5 );
$working_days = (date('N', strtotime($date)));
if($week  == 1 || $week == 3 || $week == 5){
            if($working_days == 1 || $working_days == 3 || $working_days == 5){
                         sendEmail($to, $title, $content, $content1);
                         //echo("week " .$week." -> "."1 => ".$working_days."<br>");
                         //echo("send");
            }
            else{
                echo("week " .$week." -> "."1 => ".$working_days."<br>");
                echo("do not send");
            }
        }
        else{
            if($working_days == 2 || $working_days == 4){
              sendEmail($to, $title, $content, $content1);
              //echo("week ".$week."-> "."2 => ".$working_days."<br>");
              //echo("send");
            }
            else{
                echo("week " .$week." -> "."1 => ".$working_days."<br>");
                echo("do not send");
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to learn how to use CRON jobs

Comment: Is it a user that runs this function and you only want it to run said days, or is it a crib job you want (automatically run the script at said days)?

Comment: Also what does February look like? Is it the opposite of January? Meaning first time with "x" is Tuesday the 4'th?

Comment: It will be cron job which will execute the script daily automatically but based on the script it will decide whether to run the function on that particular day or not. I hope I am able to answer your question

Comment: Ok! Just my second question also with February then it's all clear

Comment: Yes February the 4'th Tuesday it should run the function. I wouldn't say opposite but it will be kind of following the pattern by getting the last day of the month when function would be executed and first day of the month from my assumption to solve this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.
I look at the week number using date W and see if that is even or uneven.
That is what separate the weeks.

```
$date = "2020-01-06";

echo $week = date( 'W', strtotime( $date ) );
$working_days = date('N', strtotime($date));


if($week % 2 == 1){
    if($working_days == 1 || $working_days == 3 || $working_days == 5){
         sendEmail($to, $title, $content, $content1);
         //echo("week " .$week." -> "."1 => ".$working_days."<br>");
         //echo("send");
    } else{
          echo("week " .$week." -> "."1 => ".$working_days."<br>");
          echo("do not send");
    }
}else{
    if($working_days == 2 || $working_days == 4){
          sendEmail($to, $title, $content, $content1);
          //echo("week ".$week."-> "."2 => ".$working_days."<br>");
          //echo("send");
    }else{
           echo("week " .$week." -> "."1 => ".$working_days."<br>");
           echo("do not send");
    }
}
```

Comment: $date = "2020-01-06"; it wont send an email on that day but it wont even send email on 6th of February nor on 4th of February.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the working day thing in the code. I was not sure if it should trigger on "x" or not. This code as it is triggers on 2020-01-06 if working day is there

Comment: Yes it should trigger on days where "x" is crossed out

Comment: Then the edit should work. https://3v4l.org/JBglo notice how I added working days and replaced the 0 => 1

Comment: Can you please explain why you assigned week number of year instead of month to $week?

Comment: Week number is always consistent. Week of month seems more u reliable in my opinion. Maybe I'm wrong, but some months could probably go to 5 weeks, then the next will be 1. So uneven, uneven.